# Asked for hell if i do this sin and i did it

Tags: salat, sin, forgiveness, jahannam

Assalamu alaikum,

I had prayed to allah asking him to send me to hell if i did this sin and i did it. What should i do now... I feel foolish for bwing so naive. I would be very grateful for an answer.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Allah knew you wouldn’t keep your promise.

It’s the same as promising to Allah you won’t do this sin again, but end up breaking it.

You’re human. You’re not an angel. You were bound to slip up.

I get you might have used this as a scare tactic, but don’t play with hell and God’s punishments.

Just repent and don’t say anything like this again and understand you’re human. You’re prone to making errors.

Comment: Thankyou very much.

Answer (score -1):

He created us and knows us better, this is why there is repentance and asking for forgiveness.